# How to find the AVG, and STD between fixed time period using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My dataset `df` looks like this:

```
DateTimeVal            Open 
2017-01-01 17:00:00    5.1532    
2017-01-01 17:01:00    5.3522 
2017-01-01 17:02:00    5.4535    
2017-01-01 17:03:00    5.3567    
2017-01-01 17:04:00    5.1512 
....
```

It is a `minute` `diff` based dataset.

In my calculation, a single day(`24 hour`) is defined as:

`17:00:00` `Sunday` to `16:59:00` `Monday` and so on for other days

What I want to do is find the `AVG`, and `STD` of each `24 hour` from `17:00:00` `Sunday` to `16:59:00` `Monday` and so on for all the day

**What did I do?**

I did the `rolling` to find the `AVG` but it does for a `day` and not with `time-range`

```
# day avg
# 7 day rolling avg

df = (
df.assign(DAY_AVG=df.rolling(window=1*24*60)['Open'].mean()) 
df.assign(7DAY_AVG=df.rolling(window=7*24*60)['Open'].mean())
.groupby(df['DateTimeVal'].dt.date) 
.last() )
```

I need help with these 2 things:

- How do I find the `AVG`, and `STD` between fixed time period?
- How do I find the `AVG`, and `STD` between fixed time period for `7D rolling` and `14 Days rolling`?

Comment: IIUC, you can use `resample` with `base` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `resample` with `base`:

```
#Create empty dataframe for 2 days
df = pd.DataFrame(index = pd.date_range('2017-07-01', periods=48, freq='1H'))

#Set value equal to 1 from 17:00 to 16:59 next day
df.loc['2017-07-01 17:00:00': '2017-07-02 16:59:59', 'Value'] = 1

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                     Value
2017-07-01 00:00:00    NaN
2017-07-01 01:00:00    NaN
2017-07-01 02:00:00    NaN
2017-07-01 03:00:00    NaN
2017-07-01 04:00:00    NaN
2017-07-01 05:00:00    NaN
2017-07-01 06:00:00    NaN
2017-07-01 07:00:00    NaN
2017-07-01 08:00:00    NaN
2017-07-01 09:00:00    NaN
2017-07-01 10:00:00    NaN
2017-07-01 11:00:00    NaN
2017-07-01 12:00:00    NaN
2017-07-01 13:00:00    NaN
2017-07-01 14:00:00    NaN
2017-07-01 15:00:00    NaN
2017-07-01 16:00:00    NaN
2017-07-01 17:00:00    1.0
2017-07-01 18:00:00    1.0
2017-07-01 19:00:00    1.0
2017-07-01 20:00:00    1.0
2017-07-01 21:00:00    1.0
2017-07-01 22:00:00    1.0
2017-07-01 23:00:00    1.0
2017-07-02 00:00:00    1.0
2017-07-02 01:00:00    1.0
2017-07-02 02:00:00    1.0
2017-07-02 03:00:00    1.0
2017-07-02 04:00:00    1.0
2017-07-02 05:00:00    1.0
2017-07-02 06:00:00    1.0
2017-07-02 07:00:00    1.0
2017-07-02 08:00:00    1.0
2017-07-02 09:00:00    1.0
2017-07-02 10:00:00    1.0
2017-07-02 11:00:00    1.0
2017-07-02 12:00:00    1.0
2017-07-02 13:00:00    1.0
2017-07-02 14:00:00    1.0
2017-07-02 15:00:00    1.0
2017-07-02 16:00:00    1.0
2017-07-02 17:00:00    NaN
2017-07-02 18:00:00    NaN
2017-07-02 19:00:00    NaN
2017-07-02 20:00:00    NaN
2017-07-02 21:00:00    NaN
2017-07-02 22:00:00    NaN
2017-07-02 23:00:00    NaN
```

Now use, `resample` with `base=17`

```
df.resample('24H', base=17).sum()
```

Output:

```
                     Value
2017-06-30 17:00:00    0.0
2017-07-01 17:00:00   24.0
2017-07-02 17:00:00    0.0
```

---

Update for minute sampling:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value': 0}, index = pd.date_range('2018-10-01', '2018-10-03', freq='1T'))

df.loc['2018-10-01 15:00:00':'2018-10-02 18:59:50', 'Value'] = 1

df.resample('24H', base=17).agg(['sum','mean'])
```

Output:

```
                    Value          
                      sum      mean
2018-09-30 17:00:00   120  0.117647
2018-10-01 17:00:00  1440  1.000000
2018-10-02 17:00:00   120  0.285036
```

Comment: Thank you for composing the answer. One clarification, my dataset is `minute` based

Comment: @floss did this answer help you would you mind accepting?